# get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given in Yii

Tags: php, yii

i'm just research about Yii for 2 weeks but i have a project  . the mission is use Yii Cactiveform to create a form. But I get this error : get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given. This is my Controller:

```
 public function actionPersonal()
{
    // Layout
    $this->layout = '../layouts/news_style';
    // Title
    $this->pageTitle = Yii::app()->params['news_title'];
    // Description
    $this->pageDescription = Yii::app()->params['news_description'];
    // Breadcrumbs
    $this->breadcrumbs = array(
        'My Profile' => array(),
    );
    $layout = $this->_layout();
    return $this->render('my_profile', array(
        'user' => Yii::app()->user->getUser(),
        'postDoXe' => $layout['postDoXe'],
        'newPosts' => $layout['newPosts'],
    ));
}
```

my_profile.php

```
<div class="input-group">
                    <?php echo $form->label(Yii::app()->user->getUser(),'username'); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->textField(Yii::app()->user->getUser(),'username'); ?>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Yii::app()->user->getUser()
```

returns an array, but you need a model for your form elements, you have given an array for validation

```
<?php echo $form->textField(Yii::app()->user->getUser(),'username'); ?>
```

you need to populate a model using id returned from "Yii::app()->user->getUser()" and then use that model in your form

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model ,'username'); ?>
```